# How to prove the polynomial $ x^{2011}-x\in \mathbb{Z}_{2011}[x] $ is separable?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I am trying to prove that the polynomial $ x^{2011}-x\in \mathbb{Z}_{2011}[x] $ is separable.

Definition: Let K be a field  and $f\in K[x]$ an irreducible polynomial. The polynomial $f$ is said to be separable if in some splitting field of $f$ over $K$ every root of $f$ is a simple root.

My attempt:
$$\begin{align*}
x^{2011}-x&=x(x^{2010}-1)\\
&=x(x^{1005}-1)(x^{1005}+1)\\
&=x(x-1)(x^{1004}+x^{1003}+\cdots+x^{2}+x+1)(x^{1005}+1)
\end{align*}$$

But I have no idea what to do next. Any hints/ideas are much appreciated. Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: What does Fermat's little theorem say about the roots of that polynomial?

Comment: I got the idea. By Fermat's little theorem, for any $ a\in \mathbb{Z} $ , $ a^{2011} \equiv a \pmod {2011}$. Then for any $ a\in \mathbb{Z} $ , $2011|(a^{2011}-a)$. So $x^{2011}-x$ has 2011 distinct roots in $\mathbb{Z}_{2011}$.

Answer (score 2):

Another hint: A polynomial $f(x)$ has roots of multiplicities $>1$ if and only if $\gcd(f,f')$ has degree $>0$.